# Visual Studio Code PHP disable specific suggestions options

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code

In my Visual Studio Code I have the problem that the editor is suggesting to me a lot of unimportant options (see screenshot) and the classes and methods are listed after these. How can I configure the order so the methods and classes are listed at the beginning?

[image]

Comment: This question is unclear as to what you are really trying to accomplish here.  Please reword or clarify.

Comment: An example of what you would prefer it looked like might help here

Comment: You must be using any plugin/add-ons in VC. Check out settings of plugin/add-on, you will find a way

Comment: @G-Man he is trying to sort the suggestions in autocomplete (intellisense) dropdown so he can see `methods` and `classes` before other options (variables, properties,...)

Comment: The problem was indeed caused by an extension.